# Create new column based on another column from dataframe with rnorm function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying use column values in rnorm function and creating new column bound data frame.

```
> show(tablo)
      teta
1 14.67078
2 14.86293
3 15.54010
4 15.91335
5 16.05241
6 15.24349
7 15.01060
8 14.79570
```

each teta values mean values in rnorm function. First I created function

```
values <- function(x)
{
rnorm(1, x, 0.55)
}
values(tablo$teta) or attach(tablo) values(teta)
```

This function shows just one value.

which is odd.

```
a <- 1:10

test <- function(x) {
    x +20
}

test(a)
```

This function shows all new a values for a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *[apply](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family)* family of functions (e.g. `sapply`) function, as you want to utilize your function `values` on each element of a vector. Following should do the job:

```
sapply(tablo$teta,values)
#[1] 14.88455 14.07981 15.19649 16.12940 16.42719 14.69165 14.27466 13.57540
```

Your `test` function worked without using `sapply` because `+` operation in R is a vector operation. However, It did not work with `values` function because in [rnorm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compositions/versions/2.0-1/topics/rnorm), mean (i.e. 2nd argument) should be passed as a scalar if n (first argument) is 1 (while in your question are passing it in as a vector).

Comment: Well values function just showing what I want to do. I found this solution
`code`
tablo2 <- as.data.frame(NULL)

for (j in 1:8)
{
    tablo2 <- rbind(tablo2, c(rnorm(1, tablo$teta[j], V)))
}
tablo2[,1]
16.44925 15.76952 16.13598 14.87996 13.67443 14.56566 18.21521 15.24416
`code`
Your solution much cleaner. Any reason test function works but values funciton not working?

Comment: yes, loop would work, but it tends to be slower if you are running on large dataset. Using sapply as shown above would be faster on a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `length(x)` rather than `1` within `rnorm`, e.g.,

```
rnorm(length(x),x,0.55)
```

Comment: I'm trying take one sample from normal distribution with specific mean values.

Comment: @pirekare Here you will get `length(x)` normal random variables with multiple means specified by `x`, i.e., distinct means.

Comment: `test2 <- function(x){`


`rnorm(length(x), x, 0.55)`
`}`

>teta
16.99719 17.43694 17.77940 17.74896 18.45911 17.96390 17.75676 16.85919
test2(teta)
is empyt. Did not work. @S K sapply solution is what I looking for.